# How to return information (facts) set within the play job to the AWX/Ansible Tower Api Caller?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

What if you need to return data to the caller/launcher of an AWX job via API?

In your playbook you can set facts with:

```
  - name: Set the company id
    set_fact:
      tenant_id: "{{ tenant.json.id }}"
```

How could I access the tenant id from the api after calling the job?

Comment: You should get the job_id when you run the job template.  Put that variable in a `debug` statement, use an API call to get the job output, and parse that output for the variable.

Comment: @Jack do you mean the output from `/api/v2/jobs/{id}/stdout/`, get that that json and then try find the variable? That seems like the only relevant call along with `/api/v2/jobs/{id}/job_events/`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cacheable option of set_fact in your playbook/role. On the AWX side, if you enable fact caching on your inventory, the facts you have marked with "cacheable: yes" will be available as facts for the host via the AWX hosts API (hosts/{id}/ansible_facts).

Answer (score 0):

On the AWX release I am using 11.0, it cannot be done as far as I know.

The best work around would be to explicitly push that data somewhere within the play.